# How do I copy a file on the same path as a dependency jar in Maven?

Tags: maven

I have `XYZ.jar` and `XYZ.properties` from a 3rd party.
`XYZ.jar` has some code which looks for XYZ.properties at the path as `XYZ.jar`.

My problem is packaging my project which uses XYZ.jar and XYZ.properties.

I've added the jar to our repo using mvn deploy:deploy-file.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=xyz.jar -Durl=<someurl> -DgroupId=thirdparty.xyz 
-DartifactId=xyz -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=thirdparty
```

I've also added a dependency for XYZ in my project pom.xml like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>thirdparty.xyz</groupId>
    <artifiactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My question is how do I add the properties file? The two restrictions on it are

1.`XYZ.properties` has to be on the same path as the `XYC.jar`
 2. The name of the properties file has to be `XYZ.properties`. No version number/artifactid should be appended to the name.

How do I do this in maven?

I've tried packaging the properties file and add a dependency, but the path is different - i.e. it goes into its own group-artifact-version folder.

Some Clarifications :

1. The rest of my project has standard maven structure
2. Unfortunately, I cannot change the way the third-party `XYZ.jar` works.

Comment: This isn't how maven repos work. You should probably rethink what you're trying to do. Trying to force things to work in a way they aren't supposed to is usually a path to trouble.

Comment: Do you have a solution which for me which does not involve doing it this way?  Unfortunately, this is a third party jar which works this way. I have no control over it. The rest of this project and other related projects are in maven the standard way.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do in the first place. If you explain your actual problem, someone might be able to suggest a viable solution.

Comment: @RyanStewart Sorry If I was not clear. I have XYZ.jar and XYZ.properties from a 3rd party. XYZ.jar has some code which looks for XYZ.properties at the path as XYZ.jar. My problem is packaging my project which uses XYZ.jar and XYZ.properties so that it works i.e the restrictions given in the question are met. Please let me know how I can be clearer.

Comment: No problem. Some clarity is beginning to emerge, but it's not there yet--at least not for me. Your question seems to be about how to add a JAR and a properties file to a distributable package at specific paths, but you haven't yet said what kind of project you're working on or how it's being packaged. Beyond that, I fail to see what that has to do with deploying artifacts to a Maven repo, so maybe there's something here that I'm just not getting.

Comment: @RyanStewart Thank you for taking time to understand the situation. The project is being packaged as a jar. Apart from the third party `XYZ.jar` everything is as you would expect. I had to deploy `XYZ.jar` to the maven repo, so that I could add the dependency to my project, because `XYZ.jar` is not in central maven repo.

Comment: I still don't hear anything that makes me think, "Oh yeah, that's a problem." If your app is a jar, then you'll be including it and other required jars in a distributable package of some kind, right? Just put the properties file at the appropriate relative path when you're building said package. It seems pretty plain-vanilla to me. I'm not sure why the properties file is going in the Maven repo, but in any case, how and where a JAR and properties file are deployed in a repo seem completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You can deploy the properties file the same way with a different packaging if you like and then use that packaging in the dependency to it but you will not be able to dictate the name in the repo.

You can however use the dependency plugin to retrieve the artifact and give it the name you desire again..

Overall however it would be better to have the properties file in the jar..

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot have it in the jar because of the way the 3rd party jar works. Can you give me an example on how to retrieve/rename using the dependency plugin?

Comment: Pretty sure he just means [dependency:copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html). It has a [`stripVersion`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html#stripVersion) option you can set.